# navbar wider than body onl on mobile Chrome

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a problem with this simple [website](http://omnimenu.org). Only on mobile chrome browser, the width of the navbar is wider than the width of the body. I looked for fixed widths of some elements because this solved the problem for posts with the same issue but could not find it... Thank you for any suggestions..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit following `meta` tag in your head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

and following css:

```
body{
  max-width:100%;
}
.navbar-default{
  max-width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem stays for any width greater than 542px :/

Comment: Are you using bootstrap 4. If not then maybe you are using a media query.

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.7, I now tried what happens with bootstrap 4 and the result is not nice :D

Comment: oh sorry I wrote the meta tag wrong. I updated my answer. try it now